# Docking the [dokan]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

[dokan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dokan) for a long time has been referring to a Windows library. It slumbered in peace with ~5 questions per year, until one day a Wordpress developer decided to name their product the same way.

Now it is gaining traction as Wordpress plugin (already 9 questions this year). Is it time yet to separate the namesakes?

Comment: This is never popular, but I've never heard a good answer to why it's insufficient to disambiguate with the other tags. For example, when I look at [tag:dokan] questions, I don't see any Wordpress questions because I have [tag:wordpress] ignored. I do, however, see questions about the Dokan library for Windows. In my personal opinion, this is cleaner and less error-prone than having [tag:wordpress-dokan] and [tag:windows-dokan], since (A) that isn't that those libraries are actually known by, and (B) that isn't what users will type into the tag box.

Comment: @CodyGray Considering how every other burnination request that ends up in **Hot Meta Posts** features *"Good golly, look to how many things this tag refers to! That's just so wrong."*, this opinion indeed seems unopular. I guess this opposition drips down from aversion to meta tags - ie. both meta tags, and tags used the way you proposed, have no inherent meaning on their own. The difference being, of course, that the latter ***do*** gain meaning in conjuction with other tags, while the former do not.

Comment: There is widespread misunderstanding of precisely what is meant by "meta" tags. A meta tag is, by definition, a tag that does not describe the contents of the question itself. An example of a meta tag is [homework] or [beginner]---these describe the *nature* of the question, rather than the *subject* of the question. A consequence of that is that meta tags cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, but this is not sufficient to make a tag "meta". This misunderstanding leads to a lot of people proposing and justifying burnination on the grounds that a tag is "ambiguous".

Comment: Of course, this ignores that there are *lots* of ambiguous tags that should really be combined with other tags, yet we're not anxious to burninate those: [algorithm], [string], [windows], [memory-management], [inheritance], and [pointers], just to name a few. I honestly have no idea why burnination requests are so popular. I think it's just a way for people to feel like they're doing something, since anyone can suggest edits that remove tags. No one considers how extremely disruptive they are, or how much time is wasted performing these burninations. I've engaged in this rant before.

Comment: @CodyGray You say "(B) that isn't what users will type into the tag box.", true, but that ***is*** what will pop up as suggestions when the user does type just "dokan"!

Comment: @CodyGray I disagree. When you type any part of a tag into the search box it shows up. We can't allow the laziness of users to be a reason why we don't do something

Comment: @MrLister They'll type "dokan", and then they'll have to choose one of the options. Or they won't, and they'll just tag it [dokan]. Oops. I mean, you can spin it as optimizing for "laziness", or you can say that it's making the software easier to use by making it more consistent with user's expectations.

Comment: @CodyGray Aren't you ignoring the fact that one of the main uses for tags are for "subscribing" to topics a user knows a lot about, and will likely be able to contribute to? If I know a lot about WordPress Dokan and nothing about Windows Dokan, it's going to be kind of annoying that this tag refers to both.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm 100% on board with burninations, only because it's trivial to clean up most of the time and results in a slightly cleaner site each time. I don't find they're very disruptive at all; it's almost an SO-entry-level way of contributing with a clear goal that doesn't require much knowledge of the tag.

Comment: The tags are supposed to be unambiguous for anyone on the site, otherwise, we would have tags used by askers for one thing, editors for another, related parties for other, and no answerers following them.

Comment: @CodyGray: Your examples of "ambiguous" tags seem to all refer to tags that have a single high-level concept that is generally agreed upon in CS, along with a lot of possible refinements, quirks, and sub-topics, all of which rightly fall under the same umbrella term. This is emphatically *not* the case here, or in many other ambiguous tags, where there are two or more very specific but utterly unrelated concepts that coincidentally (mostly) share a name.

Comment: Since users will probably start typing "dokan" would it be okay to have the tags "dokan-wordpress" and "dokan-windows"?

Comment: I think the same as @CodyGray on this one. Both approaches have their advantages and disadvantages but the "ambiguous" tagging system by using multiple tags to define what it's about (in this case [tag:windows] and [tag:dokan]) seems to be more natural to me, especially for naming things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a terrible idea, at around 25-30 questions a year in total, it's not exactly a catastrophically urgent problem. Even what I'd consider to be fairly quiet tags can get that many questions per week; busy tags will probably get more than that many questions *per minute*.

Given that there's only a few questions, why not just manually fix them? It doesn't need fancy intervention; just a little dedication by one person. Also, once of the best ways of encouraging an amicable split is to help make a reasonable tag wiki as soon as possible, as that encourages people to pick the right place from then on.